# Problema em retirar dados de um ArrayList

Tags: java, arquivo, arraylist

Boa tarde, estou tendo uma certa dificuldade em realizar a leitura e a gravação dos dados em um arraylist. Os dados do meu arquivo TXT:

Marcos 12345

Rafaela 54321

Kaique 12345

Matheus 54321

Segue o meu código:

```
if( evento.getSource( ) == bENTRAR )
  {
     openFile();
     //Gravando records = new Gravando();
     int i = 0;
     int cont = 0;
     while( i <= grava.getListaMateria().size()-1)
     {
        System.out.println("Login:"+grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getLogin());
        System.out.println("Senha:"+grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getSenha()+"Fezes"+cont);
        if(grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getLogin().equals(l) && grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getSenha().equals(s))
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login feito com sucesso","Bem vindo",1);
              dispose();
              MenuGUI oples = new MenuGUI();
           }

       i++;
       cont++;
       } 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login ou senha incorretos","Desculpe",1);


  }
}

 public void openFile()
 {
  l = tLogin.getText();
  s = Senha.getText();
  try
  {
     input = new Scanner(new File( "login.txt" ));
  } // end try
  catch( FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException )
  {
     System.err.println( "Error opening file." );
     System.exit( 1 );
  } // end catch


  ArrayList<Gravando> lp = new ArrayList<Gravando>();
  try // read records from file using Scanner object
  {
     while(input.hasNext())
     {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("login.txt"));
        input.useDelimiter(" ");

        grava.setLogin(input.nextLine() /*input.next()*/ ); // read account number
        grava.setSenha(input.nextLine()/*input.next()*/ ); // read first name

        lp.add(grava); 
     } // end try

  }
  catch ( NoSuchElementException elementException )
  {
     System.err.println( "File improperly formed." );
     input.close();
     System.exit( 1 );
  } // end catch
  catch ( IllegalStateException stateException )
  {
     System.err.println( "Error reading from file." );
     System.exit( 1 );
  } // end catch

  grava.setListaMaterias(lp);
  input.close();
 } // end method openFile
```

O problema e quando realizo os comandos:
 System.out.println("Login:"+grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getLogin());
                  System.out.println("Senha:"+grava.getListaMateria().get(i).getSenha()+"Fezes"+cont);

Ele me retorna no meu getLogin():Kaique 12345
Ele me retorna no meu getSenha(): Matheus 54321

Mas era para ele me retorna no getLogin(): Kaique 
Mas era para ele me retorna no getSenha(): 12345

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

```
   quando tento compilar o metodo que voce me falou da a seguinte mensagem.

    LoginGUI.java:350: error: no suitable method found for add(String[])
        lp.add(linhaArquivo.split(" ")); 
          ^
method Collection.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
method List.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
method AbstractCollection.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
method AbstractList.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
method ArrayList.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método **nextLine()** está retornado toda a linha, do seu arquivo, de uma vez. Eu acredito que se você usar o **split()** consiga resolver seu problema, uma vez que este método consegue dividir uma string, nos padrões que você definir, e colocar cada parte em um array de String.

Por exemplo:

```
String linhaArquivo = input.nextLine();
String []valores = new String[2];
valores = linhaArquivo.split(" ");
```

O código a cima vai cortar a String a cada espaço em branco, ou seja, dentro do array valores, vai ficar:

```
valores[0] = "Kaique";
valores[1] = "12345";
```

Comment: Então @Marcus Vinicius, e que o problema real e que não sei quantos dados eu vou ter no meu arquivo TXT. Por isso precisaria usar um arraylist para conseguir armazenar meus dados.

Comment: @MarcosLeme Pode armazenar os dados da forma que quiser, o split() só seria uma forma de você conseguir por os valores certos no login e senha. Na parte aonde você faz os setLogin e setSenha, implementa o método e ficaria algo como setLogin(valores[0]); e setSenha(valores[1]);

Comment: Bem que você podia editar a resposta, exemplificando como usaria o split num elemento do arraylist.

Comment: @diegofm, eu editei o código, mas é bem simples, o input.nextLine() retorna cada linha do arquivo, pois está dentro de um while(input.hasNext()), é só salvar o retorno em uma String e usar o split. Não sei se era isso que você queria fizer com usar "elemento do arraylist".

Comment: @MarcusVinicius quando tento compilar o metodo que voce me falou da a seguinte mensagem.

Comment: lp.add(linhaArquivo.split(" ")); o método split() retorna uma array de string, você não vai conseguir adicionar isso no seu array lp. Você tem que continuar da mesma forma que tava fazendo antes, populando o "grava" com o que vc puxa do arquivo.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius adicionar um vetor de Strings num Arraylist que só aceita Strings?